# Why does the flann based descriptor matcher match to different keypoints everytime?

Tags: android, opencv, surf

Is it normal? When I tried the brute force matcher, the result is consistent everytime, but flann is not.
A small amount of keypoints will match to different places. I am writing the code using the Android wrapper, the keypoint detector and descriptor is SURF, something like this:

```
Mat queryDescriptors = new Mat();
Mat trainDescriptors = new Mat();
DescriptorExtractor surfDE = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.SURF);
surfDE.compute(queryImage, queryKeyPoints, queryDescriptors);
surfDE.compute(trainImage, trainKeyPoints, trainDescriptors);
DescriptorMatcher dm = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.FLANNBASED);
List<DMatch> matches = new ArrayList<DMatch>();
dm.match(queryDescriptors, trainDescriptors, matches);
```

Comment: DescriptorMatcher.create line gives me error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Andrey, [this is the reason](http://groups.google.com/group/android-opencv/browse_thread/thread/8445f90229b0b606/1f1b0c04cd1c01cd?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=flann#1f1b0c04cd1c01cd)! So yes, it is normal. To find more one would have to dissect the algorithms!

Answer (score 5):

FLANN stands for Fast Library for *Approximate* Nearest Neighbors. The approximate nearest neighbor algorithms are non-deterministic, often randomized KD-trees.

Comment: You can fix seed with `cv::setRNGSeed(2391);` before each FLANN usage. Note that this will not reliably work if you use FLANN from multiple threads at the same time.